# Intellisense from JSDoc not working for imported types in VSCode

Tags: javascript, intellisense, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

When using a, ES2015 class as a type in JSDoc it does not appear to work correctly in files that import that class via a require statement.

While working within the same file that the class was defined in, everything works as expected (shown below).

[image: An example of JSDoc typing working correctly in the same file]

While working within a different file the class appears to import correctly and show its constructor typing (shown below).

[image: An example of an imported class working correctly]

But when I try to use the class for typing (As done in the first image) it no longer considers my class as a valid type.

[image: An example of an imported class not being accepted as a type]

Here is the jsconfig I was using for this example

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
}
```

Am I just missing something in my setup or is this the expected behavior?

Comment: Did you ever managed to find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be a bit late, but line 6 of your last image should read:

```
@param {ExampleType} exampleType
```

With a lower case "exampleType", since that's what the param is named in the function.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was a typo on my part however this was just a minimum example of a trouble I've encountered multiple times. I'll upload a new file now with the mistake corrected just to illustrate that it still happens.