# JSDoc on an object's properties to describe params of a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

If I have an object (or more precisely an object assigned to `module.exports` in node) and this object's properties may consist of functions, how do I document the parameters and return value of the function?

Example:

```
module.exports = {
    /**
     * Adds two numbers together.
     * @param {number} first The first number
     * @param {number} second The second number
     * @return {number} The sum of the two numbers
    */
    "add": function(first, second) {
        return first + second;
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be supported (at least not in VSCode) and I couldn't find anywhere in JSDoc docs that describe a way to document the arguments of the function in this scenario (or just for a plain object). The JSDoc description works (it is displayed by VSCode's Intellisense), but the param definitions and return definition is not.

**Is there a way to document functions so they show up in objects that reference them?**

Comment: You might want to add the `vscode` tag to your question, as it may be specific to that program. This seems like a common problem with the IDE. Here's another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877203/intellisense-from-jsdoc-not-working-for-imported-types-in-vscode, although that was more about the capitalization. See also https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3842, although that seems to say it was fixed in more recent versions of VSCode.

Comment: Thanks. The link about capitalization led me to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This actually works correctly in VSCode. My problem was that my `@param` types didn't have proper capitalization (`Object` works while `object` does not) which means Intellisense won't work. Note: `Number` and `number` are both fine, and I suspect there are other "types" that also don't care about case sensitivity.

Comment: Dear David, I tried both `@param {Object} obj` and `@param {object} obj` and in both cases I get `(parameter) obj: any`. Do I have to set up something more in VSCode? Thank you for your time ^^